# Functional Component Calling Other Function resulting Invalid Hook Call

Tags: react-native, react-redux, react-hooks, hook

i'm new to hook.

I need to know why i can't call another function that contain hook (inside one file js)?

Below is my code :

Function A

```
const callService = async () => {

const Loginreducer = useSelector((state) => state.Loginreducer)
const email = Loginreducer.form.email;
const token = Loginreducer.credential.token;
console.log(email, token);}
```

Function B

```
const MyHomeStack = ({ navigation }) => {
    return (
        <Stack.Navigator
            screenOptions={{
                animationEnabled: false,
                title: "Some App",
                headerLeft: () => (
                    <View style={{ marginHorizontal: 10, flexDirection: "row" }}>
                        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.replace('MyTab')}>
                            <MaterialCommunityIcons style={styles.navItem} name="fish" size={25} />
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                    </View>
                ),
                headerRight: () => (
                    <View style={{ marginHorizontal: 10, flexDirection: "row" }}>
                        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() =>
                            Alert.alert("Confirmation", "Are you sure want to logout?",
                                [
                                    {
                                        text: 'OK',
                                        onPress: () => callService()
                                    },
                                    {
                                        text: 'Cancel',
                                    },
                                ],
                            )}>
                            <MaterialCommunityIcons style={styles.navItem} name="fish-off" size={25} />
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                    </View>
                )
            }}
        >
            <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
            <Stack.Screen name="Food" component={FoodScreen} />
            <Stack.Screen name="MyTab" component={MyTab} />
            <Stack.Screen name="MyDrawer" component={MyDrawer} />
        </Stack.Navigator>
    )
}
```

Function C

```
const MyTab = () => {
```

}

... etc

It works if i put the the whole const callService = async () => {} inside the const MyHomeStack above the return tag.

But i want it to be outside MyHomeStack function,
since the callService function (Function A) is need to be accessible by other function (Function C,D,etc) not just the MyHomeStack function (Function B).

Can somebody help?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hooks in React can only be used inside of function components or inside of other hooks.  See also: [Rules of Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html).

That means that you cannot call `useSelector` inside of `callService` because it is a plain function.

There a bunch of solutions.  One is to pass `state` as an argument into `callService(state)` so that it is pure function which doesn't use hooks.

Another solution is to make it into a custom hook.  You cannot execute a hook as the result of a click because this also violates the rules of hooks.  But you can call a hook to retrieve a function and then use that function as your `onClick` handler.

```
const useCallService = () => {

  // all hooks must go OUTSIDE of the callback
  const Loginreducer = useSelector((state) => state.Loginreducer);

  // return a callback  
  return (event) => {
      const email = Loginreducer.form.email;
      const token = Loginreducer.credential.token;
      console.log(email, token);
  }
}
```

```
const MyComponent = () => {
   const handleClick = useCallService();
   
   return (
      <Button onPress={handleClick} text="Click"/>
   )
}
```

Comment: hi thanks it works, but the handleClick is triggered every time MyComponent is called. 
how can i make it to be called only by onPress={handleClick} only?